# How can I remove a tag from npm?

Tags: npm

I've published a grunt plugin to npm that's been tracking the grunt 0.4 RCs by using the `master` tag. I've been publishing with:

```
npm publish --tag master
```

Now that grunt 0.4 final has been released, I've re-published my plugin as `latest` via:

```
npm publish
```

How can I now remove the `master` tag from the npm repository? It is still listed in `dist-tags` when I `npm view [my-plugin]`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It was not possible to remove dist-tags from the `npm` registry prior to `npm@2.5.0`.  There is now a command-line syntax for this, provided you update to a new version of `npm` -- see https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#try-the-latest-stable-version-of-npm for full details on upgrading.

Install latest version of npm

```
npm install -g npm    # most common way to upgrade
```

Clear a tag that is no longer in use from the package.

```
npm dist-tag rm <pkg> <tag>
```

Comment: nice to see this feature finally - thanks for update!

Answer (score 5):

Just to confirm, that (in private repo's in verdaccio), you CAN unpublish tags like this:

```
npm unpublish <name>[@<version>]
```

Which translates to (for instance):

```
npm unpublish @yourdomain/your_package@1.1.100
```

This will delete the relevant tag.

Comment: Are you sure this is for the tag and not the version?

Answer (score 3):

`master` may be in your npm config.

check what this gives:

```
npm config get tag
```

To get back to use `latest`, this should do:

```
npm config set tag latest
```

An other possibility is to un-publish the version with the `master` tag using:

```
npm unpublish <name>[@<version>]
```

this is likely to remove the tag in dist-tags (but since I haven't tried, not certain).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. `npm config get tag` returns `latest` now because it is the last tag I used to publish my plugin. I am still seeing the `master` tag in `dist-tags` when I `npm view [my-plugin]`.

Comment: but is the master tag pointing to latest version?  Or to the new version?  Or did you not change the version in package.json?

Comment: You could also try to use `npm unpublish <name>[@<version>]`, if you'd like to still have this version on npmjs, you could try to publish again with the right tag.

Comment: The latest tag is pointing to the right version. I just want to remove the master tag without unpublishing the version currently associated with it. Ideally, only the latest tag should now be associated with the plugin and listed in npm. Perhaps this is not possible?

Comment: what about unpublish old version, then publish again using `latest` instead of `master` (if you can find the right revision from git)?  There does not appear to have an option to remove a tag otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. I suppose there is no way to remove a tag without unpublishing, so I may just leave the old tag around for now.